# Enterprise Architect scripting: set Connector's property for sequence diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I created a message (sequence connector) between two elements:

```
dim w_src as EA.Element
dim w_dst as EA.Element

set w_src = Repository.GetElementByGuid("{C90B3F33-D01D-48d9-A46A-BD32CA8AF20E}")
set w_dst = Repository.GetElementByGuid("{239814DD-D331-47dc-A198-F2C32E57471C}")

Session.Output "Src: " & w_src.Name
Session.Output "Dest: " & w_dst.Name

dim w_con as EA.Connector
set w_con = w_src.Connectors.AddNew("wocMessage", "Sequence")
w_con.SupplierID = w_dst.ElementID

w_con.Stereotype = "query"

if not w_con.Update then : Session.Output "Error:" & w_con.GetLastError : exit sub : end if

w_src.Connectors.Refresh
```

How to set programmatically additional properties of the connector (like I did with Stereotype for example)? The properties I want to set are the ones I can see on User interface:

- Return Value
- Control flow type / Synch
- Control flow type / Lifecycle
- Control flow type / isReturn

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the Geert's answer, hereafter the complete code to set programmatically all the parameters provided by the user interface (Tested on EA 10):

```
dim w_src as EA.Element
dim w_dst as EA.Element

set w_src = Repository.GetElementByGuid("{C90B3F33-D01D-48d9-A46A-BD32CA8AF20E}")
set w_dst = Repository.GetElementByGuid("{239814DD-D331-47dc-A198-F2C32E57471C}")

Session.Output "Src: " & w_src.Name
Session.Output "Dest: " & w_dst.Name

dim w_con as EA.Connector
set w_con = w_src.Connectors.AddNew("wocMessage", "Sequence")
w_con.SupplierID = w_dst.ElementID

w_con.Stereotype = "query"
w_con.StyleEx = "aliasparamsTO=int, string;paramvalues=5, theString;aliasparams=5, theString;alias=theAlias;"
w_con.Subtype = "" ' Lifecycle: "New" | "Delete" | ""
w_con.Notes = "This is a note"

if not w_con.Update then : Session.Output "Error:" & w_con.GetLastError : exit sub : end if

'w_con.MiscData(0) = "Asynchronous"
dim w_params : w_params = "'retval=unsigned int;params=5, theString;paramsDlg=5, theString;retatt=returnedValue;'"
dim w_condition : w_condition = "'theCondition'"
dim w_constraint : w_constraint = "'theConstraint'"
dim w_isIteration : w_isIteration = "'Iteration'" ' 'Iteration' | NULL
dim w_synch : w_synch = "'Synchronous'" ' 'Synchronous' | 'Asynchronous'
dim w_kind : w_kind = "'Call'" ' 'Call' | 'Signal'
dim w_isReturn : w_isReturn = 0 ' 1 | 0

Repository.Execute("update t_connector set PDATA1=" & w_synch _
    & ", PDATA2=" & w_params _
    & ", PDATA3=" & w_kind _
    & ", PDATA4=" & w_isReturn _
    & ", SourceCard=" & w_isIteration _
    & ", Btm_Mid_Label=" & w_condition _
    & ", SourceConstraint=" & w_constraint _
    & " where Connector_ID=" & w_con.ConnectorID)

w_src.Connectors.Refresh

Session.Output "[OK]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to inspect the columns of t_connector.
I know life-cycle is put into Subtype, but the other parameters might be stored elsewhere.

Pay special attention to PDATA* and Style* columns. They often contain that type of information.

Comment: Thank you, actually the properties I want to set are in the PDATA* and StyleEx columns of t_connector.
Anyway, the API allows to set w_con.StyleEx = "....", but I cannot find interface to set PDATA* attributes.
Would be the SQL insert the only way to set them? I would prefer to use the API's interface.

Comment: Yes, PDATA field can be read using EA.Element.MiscData, but I'm not sure if you can use MiscData to modify them. If you can't then you can write an sql update statement and execute that using Repository.Execute(sqlString)